# How to change the class of a dropdown menu item that has been included using php

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I have attached my header and navigation to my web pages using php include function.
The navigation has an "active" class to indicate which page the user is currently viewing.

I successfully used the following code to achieve this for the regular list items.

```
<li <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

But, I cannot figure out how to achieve this for the pages within a dropdown list item.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="services.php">Services<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="web-development.php">Web Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="graphic-design.php">Graphic Design</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

The result that I am trying to achieve is, when the user is viewing the "Services", "Web Development", or "Graphic Design" page, the main "Services" list item will have a class= "active".

Comment: You should do the same thing for the other: check the current page and print `class = active` if it match the link. Since you did it for index.php, what's the issue with the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using client-side javascript.

I recommend using jQuery since is easy to use.
Just include it in your html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And use the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function, for example:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  if(url.indexOf("services.php") > -1)
    $('.dropdown-menu [href*=services.php]').addClass('active');
  //repeat the if statement for each case...
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you ElGamed. Where should i enter the function? I tried it with my other scripts within the footer and it did not work.

Comment: you can paste this code in the same file as your <li class="dropdown">... code... I'm assuming it's a PHP file?